# Transition between Views with Storyboard

Tags: ios, view, storyboard, transition

in my app I have a Tab Bar Controller that enable several tabs. One of these tabs is the one represented in the picture below:

[image]

By pressing the "i" button, the second view is opened. By pressing the "Back" button, the first view is opened again. These transitions are made with Storyboard Segues.

The problem is that if I use Modal style for the Segue, the Tab bar disappears.
My question is: only Push style Segues can be used in case of Tab bar? Is there a way to implement instead Modal transitions and keep the tab bar visible with Storyboard?

Thanks in advance, yassa

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of the same situation as with a `UINavigationController`. Using any kind of seque except for `push` will not persist the navigation bar or tab bar. The workaround for `UINavigationController` is to embed the detail view in it's own `UINavigationController`. If you think about it, this makes sense. The purpose of a modal seque is to present the user with some actionable, perhaps off-topic information. Speaking from UX theory, you normally would only provide a couple of ways out of that use case.

For a tab bar, it doesn't really make sense to use a modal seque while wanting the tab bar to remain visible as that would allow the user to navigate away from your modal view. With that said, you may try making your modal view a shortened height so that it doesn't cover up the tab bar when it's pushed onto the stack. That is untested, but it seems possible in my mind.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't understand the workaround for navigation controller, since modal segues cannot be connected to Navigation Controller. Concerning your suggestion about tab bar, I wasn't able to change size of the modal view, since being this the only view of the controller, it must be of the entire screen size... Actually I used the delegate with `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` to go back from the modal view and get again the tab bar. But it's only a partial workaround to the problem: any other suggestions will be really appreciated!!!

Comment: Click your view controller that is used as a modal and then go to `Editor->Embed in Navigation Controller`. That'll get your navigation controller in the modal view. However, you're not going to be able to add your main tab bar to the modal view. It simply doesn't align with the paradigms and normal usage of a modal view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom segue to do this.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html

And to use pushViewController instead of presentModalViewController.

```
- (void)perform
{
    // Add your own animation code here.

    [[self sourceViewController] presentModalViewController:[self destinationViewController] animated:NO];
}
```

change to

```
- (void)perform
{
    // Add your own animation code here.

    [self.sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destination animated:NO];
}
```